# Full screen canvas without messing up collisions

Tags: javascript, button, coordinates, fullscreen

I want to make a game fullscreen but when I do the click collisions are messed up, here is how things behave...

```
function fullScreen() {
    if(canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else {
      canvas.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
}
var button = {
    x:20,
    y:60,
    width:50,
    height:50
}
```

I have an event listener that listens for a click and checks if we have clicked the button using the mouse and buttons coordinates. However when we change the canvas size in the full-screen function, the coordinates are messed up and not exact with what the user is seeing, how do I fix this and align the coordinates no matter the size of the canvas?

Comment: All positions in the canvas are relative to its width/height. Imagine the canvas like an image which has an original width/height and the width/height rendered by the dom.
You should use your canvas' html width and height as a reference for your collision detection instead of its css width and height.

Comment: I thought I was using canvas width and height @Code Spirit, can you put some code to show it?